# Can I fix macOS apps from losing focus when notifications are delivered?

Tags: macos, notifications, focus

Since upgrading to Sonoma (currently on 14.3 (23D56)), focus is lost when a notification is received. This is driving me absolute mental.

It's pretty much making apps unusable - specifically when playing a game in fullscreen, notification banner is shown and suddenly, the app has lost focused. I'll have to interact / re-focus the app manually to get back.

I don't want to turn notifications off, but would accept changing things as needed to prioritize focus and still having some visible notification.

Anything I can do on macOS?

Comment: Try in Notification & Focus > turn off Preview